# What is the right way, to get a service name inside a method?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I have the following code inside a Xamarin Visual Studio .Net app:

```
[Service(Name = "MyServiceName")]
internal class MyService : Service
{
    public MyService()
    {
        var thisName = nameof(this);
    }
```

`thisName` should be `MyServiceName`. But this fails.

What is the right way, to get `MyServiceName` inside a method?

I want to get the name of the `Service`, not of a property inside the Service class.